# React native Barcode scanner getting black screen and camera not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to integrate barcode scanner in my app, i installed barcode library and did all the setup. When i run the app, camera is not opening. It getting black screen.

Pls help me out of it
[image]

```
 import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import HeaderMain from '../../../button/Header';
import Backnavigation from '../../../button/backbutton';
// @ts-ignore
import BarcodeScanner from 'react-native-scan-barcode';



const Addbook = ({navigation}:any) => {
  const [torchMode, setTorchMode] = React.useState<string>('off');
  const [cameraType, setCameraType] = React.useState<string>('back');

  const barcodeReceived = (e:any) => {
    console.log('Barcode: ' + e.data);
    console.log('Type: ' + e.type);
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      
      <BarcodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={barcodeReceived}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        torchMode={torchMode}
        cameraType={cameraType}
      />
      
    </View>
  );
};

export default Addbook;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listHeader: {
    width: '90%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Could you provide your code, please?

Comment: i added the code, pls check it out

Comment: Have you approved the camera permissions for your app in the android settings?

Comment: You mean in Android manifest file & user permission?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Have you granted your manually installed app the right permissions?

Comment: Yes i granted, user permission = camera, is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242179/discussion-between-mahish-dino-and-david-scholz).